# How to redirect all traffic to maintenance page

Tags: linux, apache, redirect, centos6, apache2.2

I am trying to force all traffic to maintenance page

```
php_value error_reporting 32767

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options -Indexes

php_flag display_errors off  

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/maintenance.html [P,L,NC]
```

I get this error

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server

Answer (score 3):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
     RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to serve a maintenance page is to use symlinks so you don't have to change the Apache configuration.

In that case, DocumentRoot could be **index.html**.  Copy **index.html** to **live.html**, and create **maintenance.html**.  When you are doing maintenance, point a symlink at **maintenance.html** and when you are done, point it back at **index.html**.

Here are the commands (Linux):

```
cp index.html live.html
vim maintenance.html (or something to create maintenance.html)
rm index.html
ln -sf maintenance.html index.html (point index.html at maintenance.html)
-- do maintenance --
ln -sf live.html index.html
```